# Refresh A gridview data

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a windows form application using c#. I am using the grdiview smart tag in visual studio 2010 to populate data from a SQL data table in to the gridview. when i add new data to the table using SQL insert, the data in the gridview remains same unless i close the application. I want to code a REFRESH button, clicking which should populate the gridview again and then it will fetch all the data including the newly inserted.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: clear the datatable and read it again. this will work i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used the assistant to connect to a database, it will generate code similar to this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'YourDatabase_ProductionDataSet.Product' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
  this.productTableAdapter.Fill(this.YourDatabase_ProductionDataSet.Product);
}
```

You can use the same line to update the database, like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.productTableAdapter.Fill(this.YourDatabase_ProductionDataSet.Product);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the datasource of a datagridview remains binded, So to refresh it set it to null and then bind other data to it again, I hope i have understood your question properly!

```
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to force a rebind

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null
dataGridView.DataSource = (DataTable)
```

Comment: i can set it to null. But how will I set the datsource back to the original table, i have used SmartTags, I don't know much about coding in this respect.